# How can I divide two polynomials so that quotient is a polynomial of infinite terms and there is no remainder?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

eg

```
num= en + c2*en^2 + c3*en^3 + c4*en^4 +O(en^5);
den= 1 + 2*c2*en + 3 c3*en^2 + 4 c4*en^3 +O(en^4);
```

Then how can I get the answer:

```
num/den=en-c2*en^2 +2(c^2-c3)en^3+(7c2*c3-4c2^3-3c4)en^4+O(en^5);
```

where `ci` are constants?
I think the correct way of getting the answer is as follow:
Series[num/den,{en,0,4}].
Thanks for your valuable time and effort.

Comment: If your series num and nem are defined as Series, then Mathemtica does this automatically. Just input num/den ....or your question is not clear.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You should elaborate your answer deeper with a working example of the OPs question.

Comment: "Just..." reminds me of "Clearly..." and the horrifying "... I leave the proofs to the reader ..." written in the days when professors acted as Emperor / Gods.

Answer (score 1):

There are several syntax errors: coefficients should be separated from the variables with a space or an asterisk to be multiplied: e.g. `c2 en^2 == c2*en^2`; `O` is an MMA command so it takes its arguments in square brackets, and the power is outside the bracket: e.g. `O[en]^5`. Then you can just type `num/den` and `Simplify` the result:

```
num = en + c2 en^2 + c3 en^3 + c4 en^4 + O[en]^5;
den = 1 + 2 c2 en + 3 c3 en^2 + 4 c4 en^3 + O[en]^4;

Simplify[num/den]
```

> en-c2 en^2+(2 c2^2-2 c3) en^3+(-4 c2^3+7 c2 c3-3 c4) en^4+O[en]^5